# Question Regarding a Proof on Change of Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Let $v_1,v_2,v_3\in \mathbb {R}^3$ be basis vectors. Suppose there exists $3 \times 3$ matrix A and distinct numbers $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$. Then $Av_i = \lambda_iv_i$ for $i = 1, 2, 3$. And $B=(v_1, v_2, v_3)$.

Let $X = (e_1, e_2, e_3)$ be the standard basis, $e_1= $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and so on. Prove that $C(B,X)AC(X,B)=$$\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &\lambda_3\end{bmatrix}$

$C(X,B)$, $C(B,X)$ are change of basis matrices.

I understand that $C(X,B)=B$ because $X=I_3$ and $C(B,X)=B^{-1}$, which leaves me with $$B^{-1}AB=
\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &\lambda_3\end{bmatrix}$$

but I got stuck here.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I’ve proved it on a concrete example with some values for $v_i$ and $\lambda_i$. It does indeed work, but I don’t understand how to prove it for a general case

Comment: How is one supposed to prove something about $C(B,X)$ when one hasn't been told what that collection of symbols means?

Comment: I don't know what your problem is.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a definition of $C(B, X)$ or $C(X, B)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $C(B2, B1)$ as the change of basis matrix:

$[v]_{B2} = C(B2, B1)[v]_{B1}$

where $[v]_{B2}$ is the coordinate with respect to the ordered basis $B2$, and similarly $[v]_{B1}$ for basis $B1$.

As $X$ contains the standard basis:

$C(X, B) = B$ and $C(B, X) = B^{-1}$

Now, for $Av_i = λ_i v_i$ for $i$ in $[1,3]$:

$$AB = A[v_1 \, v_2 \, v_3] = [Av_1 \, Av_2 \, Av_3]$$

Using matrix right multiplication:

$$= [λ_1 v_1 \, λ_2 v_2  \, λ_3 v_3]$$

Now, $B^{-1}(AB) = B^{-1}[λ_1 v_1 \, λ_2 v_2 \, λ_3 v_3]$:

$$= [λ_1 (B^{-1}v_1) \, λ_2 (B^{-1}v_2) \, λ_3 (B^{-1}v_3)]$$

Since $B^{-1}$ is the change matrix for the basis from $X$ to $B$:

$B^{-1}v_i = e_i$ where $e_i$ is the $i$-th standard vector.

Hence, the matrix will become:

$$[λ_1 e_1 \, λ_2 e_2 \, λ_3 e_3] = \begin{bmatrix} λ_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & λ_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & λ_3 \end{bmatrix}$$